# jQuery Validation submits even though it's invalid in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I believe my api addEventListener is effecting my page validation. The required field validator works perfectly. When I try the second condition that to meet the length requirement it shows the error validation but still submits the data to the api to update the database. Why is it still submitting even though it's not valid for the min length scenario?

```js
formAddUrl.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("submitting add")
  const formData = new FormData(this);

  fetch('/OfficerUrl/AddOfficerPararameter', {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData,
  });
});

formUpdateUrl.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("submitting update")

  const formData = new FormData(this);

  fetch('/OfficerUrl/UpdateOfficerPararameter', {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData,
  });
});

var beginAddValidator = $("form[name='formAddUrl']").validate({
  rules: {
    OfficerId: {
      number: true,
      required: true,
      range: [0, 9999999]
    },
    OfficerUrl: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5
    }
  },
  messages: {
    OfficerId: "Please enter a Officer Id.",
    OfficerUrl: {
      required: "Please enter a Officer Url.",
      minlength: "Url must be at least 5 characters long."
    }
  },
});

var beginUpdateValidator = $("form[name='formUpdateUrl']").validate({
  rules: {
    OfficerUrl: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5
    }
  },
  messages: {
    OfficerUrl: {
      required: "Please enter a Officer Url.",
      minlength: "Url must be at least 5 characters long."
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha512-37T7leoNS06R80c8Ulq7cdCDU5MNQBwlYoy1TX/WUsLFC2eYNqtKlV0QjH7r8JpG/S0GUMZwebnVFLPd6SU5yg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<form id="formAddUrl" name="formAddUrl" method="post">
   <div>
   <label for="OfficerId" class="col-sm-6 control-label cleanPadding">Loan Officer ID</label>
   <input name="OfficerId" id="OfficerId" class="form-control" placeholder="Officer Id" type="number" required />
   </div>
   <div>
   <label for="OfficerUrl" class="col-sm-6 control-label cleanPadding">Officer Url</label>
   <input name="OfficerUrl" id="OfficerUrl" class="form-control" placeholder="New" type="text" required />
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit" name="add" style="width: 73px;">Add</button>
</form>

<form id="formUpdateUrl" name="formUpdateUrl" method="post">
<div>
   <label class="col-sm-6 control-label cleanPadding"> Officer Url</label>
   <input id="currentUrl" class="form-control" placeholder="Current" disabled />
   </div>
   <div>
   <label for="OfficerUrl" class="col-sm-6 control-label cleanPadding">New Loan Officer Url</label>
   <input name="OfficerUrl" id="newUrl" class="form-control" placeholder="New" />
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit" name="update">Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Pleae add plugin and relevant HTML to the snippet I made you

Comment: But why not let HTML5 validate with min, max and required attributes?

Comment: and you seem to have two forms but only one submit  event handler

Comment: @mplungjan code was added but you cannot test the submit error atleast in the browser.   I have two different submit event handlers for separate api calls.

Comment: You can  - I just added console.logs. Your code seems to work just fine

Comment: You can reuse the function like this: Wrap the forms in a div with id="formsContainer" and do `document.getElementById('formsContainer').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); const tgt = e.target;
  console.log("submitting",tgt.id)
  const formData = new FormData(this);

  fetch('/OfficerUrl/'+(tgt.id === 'formAddUrl' ? 'Add' : 'Update')+'OfficerPararameter', {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData,
  });
});`